# ConcurrentModifcationException when adding value to hashmap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

The below code is receiving concurrent modificationexception when 2 thread access the same.

I would like to know whether

1. Whether this exception can be avoided if we use concurrent Hashmap.
2. If we use concurrent hashmap will there be any issue in a multithreaded environment.

or is there any other way to prevent this exception?

I donot intend use synchronzed as this code is used during polling. as one thread may have to wait for another to finish exceution.

The code is

```
HashMap<Integer, myModel> aServiceHash = new HashMap<Integer, myModel>();
HashMap<Integer, myModel> rServiceHash = new HashMap<Integer, myModel>();

for (myModel ser : serAccepted){
    aServiceHash.put(service.getOriginalDate(), ser);
}
for (myModel ser : serRequested) {
    if (aServiceHash.containsKey(service.getDate())) {
        aServiceHash.put(serv.getDate(), serv);
    }
    else 
        rServiceHash.put(service.getDate(), ser);
}
```

Referred http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-how-to-handle-concurrent-modification-exception/

http://www.journaldev.com/378/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-when-using-an-iterator

[How to avoid HashMap "ConcurrentModificationException" while manipulating `values()` and `put()` in concurrent threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621907/how-to-avoid-hashmap-concurrentmodificationexception-while-manipulating-value)

Using JSF 2.1,JDK 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap` is not thread safe. `ConcurrentHashMap`is thread safe. When accessing a map from different threads, prefer it to be concurrent for thread safety.

And yes, it will avoid the exception.There will be no multithreading issues from that direction. You'll still need to make sure no thread removes something you intend to use later.

Another way to prevent the exception is to lock the map before each insert, whether through synchronized block or a `Lock` object.

Comment: if a thread wants to remove something, should i use iterator?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` should be fine even if a thread just uses `remove()`. Of course you'll need to us iterator if this us while you are looping on the elements of the map

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your usage patterns and performance requirements, you could also build a copy-on-write map using a `volatile` `HashMap` delegate. This will give you one volatile read for each access whereas in `ConcurrentHashMap` you have a lot more, and they are a bit more expensive than ordinary reads or writes. Of course, copy-on-write schemes have their own drawbacks when you write to the map. But if you create the map from a pre-populated initial map and treat it as read-only afterwards, copy-on-write will be more efficient.